# Is the a better way to check if variable is in dict and variable is equal to dict key?

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider the following:

```
variable = "TELKOM"
registry = {,
    "CELLC": CellCSubscriber,
    "TELKOM": TelkomSubscriber,
    "HELLO MOBILE": HelloMobile,
    "VODACOM": VodacomSubscriber,
    "MTN": MTNSubscriber,
}

for k, v in registry:
    if variable == k and variable == "TELKOM":
        #do something to variable
```

Is there a better way to do this?

I have though of:

```
if variable in registry:
    #do something to variable
```

But the problem with that is, I have no way of comparing it to `"TELKOM", or am I wrong?`

Comment: I don't understand your problem? `if variable == 'TELKOM' and variable in registry:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
if variable == "TELKOM" and variable in registry:
    # do something to variable
```

Comment: Thanks.. I did not think of that... How silly the answer seems. appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Renier Why do the variable check? This is also the same thing as just saying `if "TELCOM" in registry`.

Comment: @Hoopdady - Not exactly. What if `variable` *isn't* `"TELKOM"`?

Comment: @Renier ...My bad, it only works in the case of the two equal comparisons, not using `in`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do but by the transitive property you can say

```
for k, v in registry:
    if 'TELKOM' == k:
        # do something
```

and that's the same thing.

If I had to guess though I feel like you just want to do:

```
if 'TELKOM' in registry:
    # do something
```